# How do you selectively disable jquery's on() trigger?

Tags: jquery

I have the following puzzle, and am guessing the solution is pretty obvious to some.

The idea is this: There's a list of articles. Each article initially has only the excerpt showing. Clicking anywhere in the article hides the excerpt and shows the full story, with photo. Clicking the article again (or another article) would close that open article, and re-show the excerpt.

Trouble is, I'm also using fancybox to enlarge the image. When I click the image thumbnail, I get the undesired effect of also closing the article.

How do you disable the jquery "on()" call for image clicks, while leaving the fancybox triggering intact?

p.s. Not sure the code below works, it's a simplification of something that does work...

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <h1>Article One</h1>
    <div class="first">
        Article excerpt
    </div>
    <div class="second" style="display:none">
        <a href="#" class="fancybox"><img src="blah.jpg"></a>
        Article in full
    </div>
</article>

<article>
    <h1>Article Two</h1>
    <div class="first">
        Article excerpt
    </div>
    <div class="second" style="display:none">
        <a href="#" class="fancybox"><img src="blah.jpg"></a>
        Article in full
    </div>
</article>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $('article').on('click',function(){
        $('div').hide();
        $('div.excerpt').show();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('div').fadeIn();
    });

    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

The following image shows the two states ... before and after click.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work, although it might disable the fancybox:

```
$('article a.fancybox').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If the above doesnt work, try this:

```
$('article').on('click',function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).is('a.fancybox')) {
        $('div').hide();
        $('div.excerpt').show();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('div').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/Ey5TU/1/

Your code didn't work though so I changed it to this:

```
$('article').on('click',function(){
    $('div.first, div.second').toggle();
    var otherArticles = $('article').not(this);
    otherArticles.find('div.second').hide();
    otherArticles.find('div.first').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I ended up using `if (e.target.nodeName !='IMG')` ... long live stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the clicked element (or its child), through `event.target`, has the `fancybox` class.

```
$('article').on('click', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass('fancybox') || $target.children().hasClass('fancybox')) return;
    $('div').hide();
    $('div.excerpt').show();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest('div').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stopPropagation on the fancybox plugin, to prevent it to bubble down to the article. But you could also look on your own method and look who is triggering it

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('article').on('click',function(e){
        if(e.target === this) {
            $('div').hide();
            $('div.excerpt').show();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).closest('div').fadeIn();
        }
    });
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

The problem here is that if you have any element inside your article and if you want to it to trigger the "close" event you need to add that to the OK condition, or else you just look if e.target has an claass of fancybox, if not then trigger the animation.